# How to fetch propertie's image URLs using php rets server?

Tags: php, laravel, rets, phrets, mls

I want to fetch all the image `url` related to a particular property, but `$rets->GetObject` function is not returning the image `url`.
Please help me to find where i am wrong?

I want to fetch the image URLs for the MLS property number = W******. But it is not returning any image URL.

Below is my code:

```
    $photos = $rets->GetObject("Property", "Photo", "W******", "*", 1);
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: @troydavisson Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

RETS servers are not required to support the delivery of object URLs which, it sounds like, is what you're running into here.  Some servers do provide a Media resource that might give the URLs, but you may not have that luxury with this particular feed.

If you still need URLs, you'll likely need to retrieve and store the photos yourself, maybe using a cloud hosting service.